# when i am running the Angular Pusher application …I am getting an error

Tags: angularjs, pusher

```
TypeError: Not a buffer at new Hmac (crypto.js:226:17) at Object.Hmac (crypto.js:224:12) at Object.module.exports.Pusher.createSignedQueryString (E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\node_modules\pusher\lib\pusher.js:167:43) at Object.module.exports.Pusher.post (E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\node_modules\pusher\lib\pusher.js:84:28) at Object.module.exports.Pusher.trigger (E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\node_modules\pusher\lib\pusher.js:69:17) at E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\server.js:58:10 at callbacks (E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at param (E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11) at pass (E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5) at Router._dispatch (E:\angular-pusher-gh-pages\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:173:5)
```

Comment: its not a question, plsease explain what are you do and what your expectation and please provide maximal information

Comment: When i running the Angular pusher application in node.js server i got the following error.pusher notifications can n't work,when i am update the data using http://localhost:3000/api/items  it can't load from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this happens when you haven't setup your Pusher appId, key, and secret in server.js.

```
var pusherConfig = {};
try {
  pusherConfig = require('./pusherConfig');
} catch (err) {
  pusherConfig.appId = process.env.PUSHER_APP_ID;
  pusherConfig.key = process.env.PUSHER_KEY;
  pusherConfig.secret = process.env.PUSHER_SECRET;
}
```

As you can see it looks for the Pusher appId, key, and secret in environment variables and if they aren't set then the HMAC will fail as per your error.

Let me know if that fixes it.